# Server randomly freezes

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

Im facing a very strange issue, my debian squeeze freezes up always at night (Berlin, time).
Here is what i get from a time and after doing this a few times, it becomes frozen and must be hard-reset.

**From /var/log/messages**

```
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204251] CPU 1:
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204251] Modules linked in: xt_multiport     nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_recent xt_state nf_conntrack xt_tcpudp iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables hwmon_vid snd_hda_codec_atihdmi snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm radeon snd_timer ttm drm_kms_helper snd k10temp i2c_piix4 soundcore snd_page_alloc edac_core parport_pc drm i2c_algo_bit i2c_core shpchp pci_hotplug pcspkr edac_mce_amd parport wmi evdev processor button ext3 jbd mbcache raid1 md_mod sd_mod crc_t10dif ata_generic ahci ohci_hcd pata_atiixp e100 mii libata xhci floppy ehci_hcd thermal thermal_sys usbcore scsi_mod nls_base [last unloaded: i2c_dev]
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204251] Pid: 758, comm: flush-9:0 Tainted: G    B      2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 GA-78LMT-USB3
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204251] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff810b3506>]  [<ffffffff810b3506>] find_get_pages_tag+0x66/0xdd
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204251] RSP: 0018:ffff8804235e7b30  EFLAGS: 00000286
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204251] RAX: ffffffffffffffff RBX: ffff8804235e7c00 RCX: 0000000000000000
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204251] RDX: 0000000000040000 RSI: ffffea000496b2a8 RDI: ffffea000496b2a0
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204251] RBP: ffffffff8101166e R08: ffff8804235e7af0 R09: 0000000000000000
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204251] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000040000 R12: ffff8804235e7c08
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204251] R13: 0000000d22678a20 R14: ffff8804235e7af0 R15: 00000000091b9060
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204251] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff880010440000(0000) knlGS:000000007ebf7b70
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522] CS:  0010 DS: 0018 ES: 0018 CR0: 000000008005003b
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522] CR2: 00000000dec86000 CR3: 0000000001001000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522] Call Trace:
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff810bb792>] ? pagevec_lookup_tag+0x1a/0x21
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff810ba330>] ? write_cache_pages+0x162/0x327
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff810b9d48>] ? __writepage+0x0/0x25
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff8110758a>] ? writeback_single_inode+0xe7/0x2da
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff81108290>] ? writeback_inodes_wb+0x424/0x4ff
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff81108497>] ? wb_writeback+0x12c/0x1ab
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff8110870d>] ? wb_do_writeback+0x14f/0x165
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff81108754>] ? bdi_writeback_task+0x31/0xaa
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff810c8664>] ? bdi_start_fn+0x0/0xd0
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff810c86d4>] ? bdi_start_fn+0x70/0xd0
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff810c8664>] ? bdi_start_fn+0x0/0xd0
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff81064ac1>] ? kthread+0x79/0x81
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff81011baa>] ? child_rip+0xa/0x20
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff81064a48>] ? kthread+0x0/0x81
Dec 11 01:36:11 srv156 kernel: [125983.204522]  [<ffffffff81011ba0>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
```

**From /var/log/syslog**

```
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.162930] BUG: Bad page map in process java  pte:14fa4f067 pmd:424b54067
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.162937] page:ffffea000496c148 flags:0200000000000878 count:2 mapcount:-1 mapping:ffff88014f8d7de8 index:2f4
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.162946] addr:0000000009096000 vm_flags:00100077 anon_vma:ffff880422410d40 mapping:(null) index:9096
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.162955] Pid: 21356, comm: java Tainted: G    B      2.6.32-5-amd64 #1
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.162961] Call Trace:
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.162966]  [<ffffffff810ca4bf>] ? print_bad_pte+0x232/0x24a
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.162973]  [<ffffffff810cb56f>] ? unmap_vmas+0x62d/0x931
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.162980]  [<ffffffff810cfc74>] ? exit_mmap+0xc4/0x148
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.162986]  [<ffffffff8104bbc1>] ? mmput+0x3c/0xdf
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.162992]  [<ffffffff8104f81e>] ? exit_mm+0x102/0x10d
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.162998]  [<ffffffff81051243>] ? do_exit+0x1f8/0x6c9
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.163004]  [<ffffffff81071abb>] ? futex_wake+0xd6/0xe7
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.163010]  [<ffffffff8105178a>] ? do_group_exit+0x76/0x9d
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.163016]  [<ffffffff8105df9f>] ? get_signal_to_deliver+0x310/0x339
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.163023]  [<ffffffff81010037>] ? do_notify_resume+0x87/0x73f
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.163029]  [<ffffffff810cc664>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x7aa/0x80f
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.163036]  [<ffffffff81073f14>] ? compat_sys_futex+0x10d/0x12b
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.163043]  [<ffffffff812fb546>] ? do_page_fault+0x2e0/0x2fc
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.163049]  [<ffffffff81010e0e>] ? int_signal+0x12/0x17
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.163114] BUG: Bad page state in process java  pfn:14fa0c
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.163120] page:ffffea000496b2a0 flags:020000000002001c count:0 mapcount:-1 mapping:ffff88039dc0db30 index:11e3
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164563] Pid: 21356, comm: java Tainted: G    B      2.6.32-5-amd64 #1
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164570] Call Trace:
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164578]  [<ffffffff810b71a9>] ? bad_page+0x116/0x129
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164586]  [<ffffffff810b7692>] ? free_pages_check+0x38/0x57
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164595]  [<ffffffff810b89cf>] ? free_hot_cold_page+0x46/0x190
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164603]  [<ffffffff810b8b82>] ? __pagevec_free+0x69/0x7f
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164611]  [<ffffffff810bba3f>] ? release_pages+0x137/0x18d
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164620]  [<ffffffff810d8559>] ? free_pages_and_swap_cache+0x57/0x73
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164629]  [<ffffffff810cb5ed>] ? unmap_vmas+0x6ab/0x931
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164637]  [<ffffffff810cfc74>] ? exit_mmap+0xc4/0x148
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164644]  [<ffffffff8104bbc1>] ? mmput+0x3c/0xdf
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164652]  [<ffffffff8104f81e>] ? exit_mm+0x102/0x10d
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164660]  [<ffffffff81051243>] ? do_exit+0x1f8/0x6c9
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164667]  [<ffffffff81071abb>] ? futex_wake+0xd6/0xe7
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164675]  [<ffffffff8105178a>] ? do_group_exit+0x76/0x9d
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164683]  [<ffffffff8105df9f>] ? get_signal_to_deliver+0x310/0x339
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164692]  [<ffffffff81010037>] ? do_notify_resume+0x87/0x73f
Dec 10 21:20:29 srv156 kernel: [110625.164700]  [<ffffffff810cc664>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x7aa/0x80f
```

The last piece of log, has been recently posted, because I've just found it. It seems Java process do something and began to slowly eat all the resources of the server. I don't know exactly if this could be the root cause.

Im using Debian Squeeze.
uname -a

```
Linux srv156 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 11:00:33 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I really will appreciate your help, i dont know what more to do.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? When anything electronic spontaneously shuts down, high temperature is one aspect you should check.

Comment: No, it doesnt shut down, it hangsup. I need to hardreset it. Could be a failing core of the cpu? it has a opteron 4 core.

Comment: Anything related about that point in time? Some Cron job running causing a lot of I/O or memory usage that may be related? And what do you mean by "freezes up always at night"? `125983 / 60 / 60` = 35 hours of uptime.

Comment: Have you given it a dose of memtest86? Have you tried unloading some of the unneeded kernel modules (for a debian server this box has an awful lot of stuff loaded that a server never needs...)? Try setting up a cronjob a few minutes before the "scheduled" crash that dumps pstree -pa , uptime, the contents of /proc/[useful things - slabinfo, meminfo, interrupts....] , ... into a file (sync!) or email... Also, why are there tainted kernel modules on a server (manually compiled stuff that might have been built with a mismatched compiler?)

Comment: I edited original question with new data i found. @rackandboneman I don have idea, i took this server 4 months ago and it was running and deeply config. At the beggining we tought it was a hardware problem, but this sunday we changed the motherboard and 35 hours later crashed again.@gertvdijk there's only a cronjobs for backups and at 01:00 a ntp update. Nothing more.

Comment: Experiment to try if the application can stomach it: shut down ntp and make the clock run a few minutes ahead of time (*do not* set it backwards manually ever without a reboot, let ntp deal with it after experiment is done). Monitor when exactly server dies...

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a memory problem - the bad pages.  Do you have mcelog configured - do you have any files?  http://mcelog.org/

Comment: Yesterday i did it and got traces. This times whats a problem with the  Apache (!!!) so it means something its messing with everything it touchs, probably RAM

Answer (score 6):

Your kernel is tainted with `B` flag, [which means](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3582750):

> B: A process has been found in a Bad page state, indicating a
>   corruption of the virtual memory subsystem, possibly caused by
>   malfunctioning RAM or cache memory.

Also backtraces in `/var/log/syslog` says about `Bad page map`, so as @Jim have already mentioned, you should probably check your ram.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know hat about B on trace calls, nice to know. Today we have programmed a maintenance on the server to change RAM. I will keep you fellows updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After 30 days, the server stopped freezing up.

It turns out it was a problem with the memory. 
Thanks to all folks!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @mdpc More importantly, as this answer if from the OP, [mark the answer accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you're able!

Answer (score 0):

When you get call traces something is definitely wrong.

Could be flacky hardware (try to do some long memtest86 runs, SMART short & long self tests, use vendor diagnostic if you have them, etc.) or some corrupt binaries on the filesystem.

If you are pretty sure hardware is ok, I would re-format the driver (I mean mkfs a new filesystem) and re-install the whole system.

Comment: Thanks, but its impossible, its on a hosting and it costs a lot to do : open kvm, do backup, reinstall. Impossible at all. But really, thanks.

Comment: If the hardware is not yours then you should pretend them to check and fix it for free. If the problem lies in the software (corrupt fs / files) then it's your problem, reinstalling would be expansive and yield a sane production server, fixing file-by-file could make it work more or less but I wouldn't ever call it production-ready.